# Why does programm throws double free detected in tcache 2 while using single linked list

Tags: c++, memory, singly-linked-list, alloc

Im trying to create function to delete from single-linked list all elements with value smaller as next (following) element value. For some reason programm throws "free():double free detected in tcache 2". What is wrong with my function ?
list is not empty.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Elem
{
    int num;
    Elem* next;
};

void deleteFromLinkedList(Elem* list) {
    Elem* curr, * next, *prev;
    curr = list;
    next = list->next;
 
    while (next != NULL)
    {
        if (curr->num < next->num) {
          
             prev->next=next;
             delete curr;
             curr = prev;
            continue;
           
        }
       prev = curr;
        curr = next;
        next = curr->next; 
    };
}
int main()
{
    Elem* first = NULL, * last = NULL, * p;
    int i;
    cout << "Enter any number or 0 to finish: ";
    cin >> i;
   
    while (i != 0)
    {
        p = new Elem;
        p->num = i;
        p->next = NULL;
        if (first == NULL)
        {
            first = last = p;
        }
        else
        {
            last->next = p;
            last = last->next;
        };
        cout << "Enter any number or 0 to finish: ";
        cin >> i;
    };
    deleteFromLinkedList(first);
```

Comment: EXAMPLE: 
Before deleting: 15,12,11,7,9,5,2,3
after deleting: 15,12,11,9,5,3

Comment: Please show a [mre] - chances are your bug starts somewhere else already

Comment: Likely means you attempt to delete the same node more than 1 time.

Comment: `void deleteFromLinkedList(Elem* list) {` Problem #1 is you pass a pointer to the head node by value not by reference. This means you could never update the pointer to the head `node` even if deleteFromLinkedList() was properly implemented.

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger with pen and paper.  Use the pen and paper to draw the nodes and links as you traverse the tree with the debugger.

Comment: @Arsenyev01 please stop making edits to your question in ways that invalidate existing comments and answers. I have reverted all of your recent edits. If you have new information to provide, append the info after the previous content, or post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of problems with your code.

`next = list->next;` is *undefined behavior* if the list is empty (ie `list` is null).

`prev->next=next;` is *undefined behavior* for the 1st node in the list, as `prev` is unassigned.

You are not updating `curr` after `delete`'ing the node it points at, which is also *undefined behavior*.

The `list` pointer is being passed in *by value*, so the caller's pointer can't be updated if the 1st node in the list is freed, thue the caller will be left with a dangling pointer to invalid memory.

Try this instead:

```
void deleteFromLinkedList(Elem* &list) {

    if (!list)
        return;

    Elem *curr = list, *next = list->next, *prev = NULL;

    while (next)
    {
        if (curr->num < next->num) {
            if (prev)
                prev->next = next;
            else
                list = next;
            delete curr;
        }
        else {
            prev = curr;
        }
        curr = next;
        next = curr->next;
    }
}
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/fvCAeK)

---

**UPDATE:** In comments, you changed your requirements to need the list scanned in multiple iterations. The code above works fine for 1 iteration, so you could simply call it multiple times in a loop until there are no more removals performed, eg:

```
bool deleteFromLinkedList(Elem* &list) {

    if (!list)
        return false;

    Elem *curr = list, *next = list->next, *prev = NULL;
    bool anyRemoved = false;

    while (next)
    {
        if (curr->num < next->num) {
            if (prev)
                prev->next = next;
            else
                list = next;
            delete curr;
            anyRemoved = true;
        }
        else {
            prev = curr;
        }
        curr = next;
        next = curr->next;
    }

    return anyRemoved;
}
```

```
...
while (deleteFromLinkedList(first));
...
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/YXTLAg)

Comment: Yes, but this deletes only  one element. -1
Im trying to create function to delete from single-linked list all elements with value smaller as next. 
So 9,8,7,12,11,6   would be  12,11,6

Comment: @Arsenyev01 If you have a function that removes one node, you can call it for each node that needs removal. But watch out for Schlemiel the Painter.

Comment: @Arsenyev01 You originally provided the example `15,12,11,7,9,5,2,3` should produce `15,12,11,9,5,3` and the code I provided does exactly that correctly, and the demo I provided proves that. I just now tried your new example `9,8,7,12,11,6` and the output is `9,8,12,11,6` not `12,11,6`. Why would `9,8,7,12,11,6` produce `12,11,6` if `9` is not less than `8`? You seem to be expecting `9,8,7` to be removed because they are all less than `12`. You have clearly changed your requirements after I have posted my answer. Please don't do that...

Comment: @Arsenyev01 If your requirements have changed, accept the original question as asked, and post a new question for the new requirement (AFTER you have attempted a solution based on what you have learned from this answer, of course).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why would 9,8,7,12,11,6 produce 12,11,6 if 9 is not less than 8?
 In result it should be numbers in descending order, where each number is not less than next. 
9,8,7,12 first iteration - 7 less than 12  7 is deleted
9,8,12 second iteration - 8 less than 12 , 8 is deleted. 
Sorry, I made mistake when posted requirements for the first time

Comment: @Arsenyev01 you didn't say anything earlier about needing multiple iterations. Again, you keep changing requirements after the fact, so how do you expect anyone to give you an accurate answer? For future reference, please POST ALL RELEVANT DETAILS UP FRONT when asking a new question. In any case, the code I already gave you works fine on 1 iteration, so you could simply call it in a loop until there are no more removals performed ([working demo](https://ideone.com/YXTLAg)).  I have updated my answer to show this.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you for your help a lot ! A will take into account your advice . 
you didn't say anything earlier about needing multiple iterations. - I said "ALL" elements should be deleted.

Comment: @Arsenyev01 "*I said "ALL" elements should be deleted*" - yes, but you didn't make clear what the rules were of HOW they needed to be deleted.